# How do I edit an exe to save settings to a different path?

Tags: exe, hex-editors

I am using a piece of software that makes the mistake of saving settings to the local appdata folder in windows, and I need it to save to the roaming appdata folder as is the best practice. The developers no longer support the product. Is it possible in any way for me to hack the EXE and edit the settings path? I tried opening the EXE in a hex editor and searching for "settings" or "appdata" or "local" and it found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the software probably.
What I'd do, if it really mattered, would do something with application virtualization. But that only works in certain cases.

EDIT: Look up Cameyo

Comment: Very cool idea, and I'll prob use Cameyo for some other stuff. For my job though, need a more legit solution.